# Can I call a class that doesn't have an activity withIntent?

Tags: android, class, android-intent, android-activity

I am having three classes namely `MainActivity`,`Timer_Service` which extends service and `LockedActivity`  which has an Activity. Now I want to use an intent like this

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Timer_Service.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

I expect it to work, but it's not working.

Comment: You should call startService(intent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if "Timer_Service" is activity then your below code work fine.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Timer_Service.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

but currently "Timer_Service" is service then try below code:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Timer_Service.class);
startService(intent);
```